# Disable scrolling, but maintain ability to zoom

Tags: javascript, ios, css, safari, lightbox

On a responsive site I'm developing I have my own little lightbox-script which opens images fullscreen while maintaining their aspect ratio. It's pretty simple, uses 2 divs (outer fullscreen-div with black background "lbBlack" and inner div with image "lbImg"):

```
//super small lightbox ;)
$("#posts").on("click", ".img", function(event) {
    $('#lbBlack').css('top',$(document).scrollTop());
    $('#lbImg').attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
    $('#lbBlack').css('width',$(window).width());
    $('#lbBlack').css('height',window.innerHeight);
    $('#lbBlack').fadeIn(500);
    $('#lbImg').css('margin-top',((window.innerHeight-$('#lbImg').height()))/2);
    document.body.style.overflow="hidden";
    document.ontouchmove = function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    $('#lbBlack').on("click", "#lbImg, body", function(event) {
        $('#lbBlack').fadeOut(500);
        document.body.style.overflow="visible";
        document.ontouchmove = function(event){
            return true;
        }
    });
});
```

For iOS, I had to add the ontouchmove-prevention, because body-overflow-hidden wasn't enough to avoid scrolling while the lightbox is opened.

Now the "big problem" for this working solution above: I want to enable zooming on the image. This is prevented with the "ontouchmove"-code.

Any ideas?

HTML-code:

```
<body>
    <div id="lbBlack">
        <img id="lbImg">
    </div>.....
```

CSS-code:

```
#lbBlack {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    background-color: black;
    z-index: 2001;
    text-align: center;
}
#lbBlack #lbImg {
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

So I think what I am looking for is a method to prevent scrolling while still maintaining the possibility to zoom. I still don't get it why body-overflow:hidden still has the ability to scroll on iOS??

Comment: Did you try setting overflow-x and overflow-y instead of overflow? Or, maybe set the overflow-x, overflow-y, or maybe overflow property on the  #lbBlack div itself instead of the body.

Comment: just tried that, doesn't work either...

Comment: Gimmie a sec I swear I've been through this before. Let me fiddle around with this on jsFiddle for a minute. Can you please post relevant  html and css?

Comment: I'll even give you hours because I need some sleep now :) thanks!

Comment: Ah OK lol. Yeah, if you post some html and css to go along with it I will check it out.

Comment: just added it above... thx buddy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Raphael,

this might not be perfect, but it should get you going in the right direction. I tested on Android, my buddy who handles the Apple stuff is unavailable at the moment. Scrolling and other moving is disabled, but you can zoom. One problem, however, is when you are actually in the process of pinch zooming you can move the picture around. You could always snap the picture back to the center after the pinch zoom is complete. (That might even look neat).

Notice I added a method to the jQuery prototype and a property to the jQuery.Event prototype.

```
/*global console, $*/
/*jslint browser: true*/

(function () {
    "use strict";


    $.fn.detectPinch = function () {
        var numTouches = 0;

        // each finger touch triggers touchstart
        // (even if one finger is already touching)
        $(document).on('touchstart', function (event) {
            // if numTouches is more than 1, reset it to 0
            // or else you can have numTouches >= 2 when
            // actually only one finger is touching
            numTouches = (numTouches > 1) ? 0 : numTouches;
            // if numTouches is 0 or 1, increment it
            numTouches = (numTouches < 2) ? numTouches += 1 : 2;
            console.log(numTouches + ' start');

        }).on('touchend', function (event) {
            // another safety check: only decrement if > 0
            numTouches = (numTouches > 0) ? numTouches -= 1 : 0;
            console.log(numTouches + ' end');

        });

        // all event objects inherit this property
        $.Event.prototype.isPinched = function () {
            return (numTouches === 2) ? true : false;
        };
        return this;
    };

    $(document).ready(function (event) {
        // call the method we added to the prototype
        $(document).detectPinch();

        $("#posts").on("click", "img", function (event) {
            $(this).css('visibility', 'hidden');
            $('#lbBlack').css('top', $(document).scrollTop());
            $('#lbImg').attr('src', $(this).attr('src'));
            $('#lbBlack').css('width', $(window).width());
            $('#lbBlack').css('height', window.innerHeight);
            $('#lbBlack').fadeIn(500);
            $('#lbImg').css('margin-top', ((window.innerHeight - $('#lbImg').height())) / 2);
            document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
        });

        $('#lbBlack').on("click", "#lbImg, body", function (event) {
            $('#lbBlack').fadeOut(500);
            $('#posts img').css('visibility', 'visible');
            document.body.style.overflow = "visible";
        });

    }).on('touchmove', function (event) {
        // prevent one-finger movements
        if (!event.isPinched()) {
            event.preventDefault();
            console.log('prevented');
        }

    });
}());
```

Comment: that looks fantastic, I'll try it out asap and give feedback here. Do I need the prototype-library for your code?

Comment: Thanks. It only uses jQuery.

Comment: very sorry @orb - I didn't have time yet :( I'll update here asap, promised!

Comment: I accept your solution even though I did not have time to try it in real life yet, but I'm sure your answer will help me solve the problem. Thanks again!

Comment: OK Thanks. If you have any issues just post another message here.